# How to differentiate an expression with respect to a symmetric matrix?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, partial-derivative, symmetric-matrices

Sorry for the basic query. I would like to understand the difference between the differentiation of an expression with respect to a matrix and with respect to a symmetric matrix.

Suppose that I have the following symmetric matrix

$M = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
b & c
\end{bmatrix}$,

and I would like to differentiate $f = a \, c - b^2$ with respect to this symmetric matrix.

According to the referecne, which does not provide detailed explanation, the solution is $\begin{bmatrix}
c & -b \\
-b & a
\end{bmatrix}$, but how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Notice that $f=\det M$. So you really want to find the gradient  $\frac{\partial\det M}{\partial M}$.  There are lots of questions on this site addressing that.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I searched for differentiation with respect to symmetric matrices but I couldn't find useful information.